# Kafka broker times out connecting to zookeeper unless i reboot ubuntu kernel

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

sorry but i am racking my brains to figure this out.
My kafka broker says waiting to connect to zookeper and then shuts down (time out).I checked broker config / port did netstat etc also confirmed zookeper settings. But then if i restart my ubuntu kernel (where kafka broker is running) all is well.  Zookeeper is on Linux mint.  Please can someone advice where what log files can give me more detail - i did the usual netstat and lsof no luck.

Answer (score 0):

its windows 10 for some reason it is not recognizing my partitioned ip.
Fixed it was a config item on my end.